# Default value for missing attributes in xpath expression

Tags: c, xpath, libxml2

I'm retrieving with cURL an XML that get parsed with libxml2 and xpath. Results (keyword) fill my 2D array (myarray). It works great!
But the XML I get (current weather data for a specified City based on openweathermap.org), depending on weather condition, have sometimes missing attributes:
Ex.

If sky is clear XML is like:

```
<current>
<city id="4219762" name="Rome">
<coord lon="-85.164673" lat="34.257038"/>
<country>US</country>
<sun rise="2013-06-18T10:28:40" set="2013-06-19T00:55:19"/>
</city>
<temperature value="21.59" min="21" max="22" unit="celsius"/>
<humidity value="88" unit="%"/>
<pressure value="1014" unit="hPa"/>
<wind>
<speed value="1.03" name="Calm"/>
<direction value="87.001" code="E" name="East"/>
</wind>
<clouds value="75" name="broken clouds"/>
<precipitation mode="no"/>
<weather number="701" value="mist" icon="50n"/>
<lastupdate value="2013-06-18T05:35:00"/>
</current>
```

while if it's rainy is like:

```
//same as above
<precipitation value="0.125" mode="rain" unit="3h"/>
//same as above
```

The problem is that in the first case myarray get 9 lines:

```
id: 0 string: 3171168
id: 1 string: Pescara
id: 2 string: IT
id: 3 string: 24.646
id: 4 string: 92
id: 5 string: 5.7
id: 6 string: Moderate breeze
id: 7 string: no
id: 8 string: Sky is Clear
```

while in the second get 10 lines:

```
id: 0 string: 3171168
id: 1 string: Pescara
id: 2 string: IT
id: 3 string: 24.646
id: 4 string: 92
id: 5 string: 5.7
id: 6 string: Moderate breeze
id: 7 string: 0.125
id: 8 string: rain
id: 9 string: broken clouds
```

so when I print myarray in main function

```
printf("Cloudiness:%s",myarray[8]);
```

if sky is clear i get correct vuales, but if it's rainy I get inconsistent data (cause now Cloudiness is in line 9). The same behavior could be applied if other nodes/attributes are missing for some specific server side issues.
Is there a way to specific a **default value** (Ex. N/A) for missing nodes/attributes so myarray get always **consistent** data (and lines get respectively the same type of information)? Have someone had the same issue? Is there a workaround?
Thanks for helping,
Best,
Giovanni.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>

    struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};

    static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;
    mem->memory = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if (mem->memory == NULL) {  /* out of memory! */ 
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;
    return realsize;
}

    xmlXPathObjectPtr getnodeset (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlChar *xpath) {
    xmlXPathContextPtr context;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;
    context = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
    if (context == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathNewContext\n");
        return NULL;    }
    result = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpath, context);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(context);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathEvalExpression\n");
        return NULL;    }
    if(xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(result->nodesetval)){
        xmlXPathFreeObject(result);
        printf("No result\n");
        return NULL;    }
    return result;
}

    int xmlretrive(char* myurl, char* myxpath, char*** myarray) {
    CURL *curl_handle;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) myxpath;
    xmlNodeSetPtr nodeset;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;
    int i;
    xmlChar *keyword;
    struct MemoryStruct chunk;
    chunk.memory = malloc(1);
    chunk.size = 0;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, myurl);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
    curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
        //printf("%s\n", chunk.memory);
    doc = xmlParseDoc(chunk.memory);
    if (doc == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
            return NULL;    }
    result = getnodeset (doc, xpath);
    if (result) {
        nodeset = result->nodesetval;
        *myarray = malloc((nodeset->nodeNr + 1) * sizeof(*myarray));
        for (i=0; i < nodeset->nodeNr; i++) {
            keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
            (*myarray)[i] = malloc(strlen(keyword)+1);
            if ((*myarray)[i] == NULL) {
            // out of memory.  print error msg then exit
            }
            strcpy((*myarray)[i], keyword);
            xmlFree(keyword);
        }
        xmlXPathFreeObject (result);
    }
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    if(chunk.memory)
    free(chunk.memory);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return i-1;
}

    int main(void)  {
char thisxpath[300];
char thisurl[200];
char** myarray = NULL;
char output[900] = "";
int arr_rows;
strcpy (thisurl,"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Rome&mode=xml&units=metric");
strcpy (thisxpath,"//city/@*[name()='name' or name()='id'] | //country | //weather/@value | //temperature/@value | //precipitation/@*[name()='value' or name()='mode'] | //humidity/@value | //speed/@*[name()='name' or name()='value']");
arr_rows = xmlretrive (thisurl, thisxpath, &myarray);

    // for cycle to print myarray with some great layout

free(myarray);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were using XPath 2.0 the following construction would work:

```
(/precipitation/@value, "NA")[1]
```

However, since you're using libxml2, I believe you're stuck with XPath 1, in which that won't work.

In either case, I'd suggest a different approach. Rather than using one big complex XPath to select a bunch of nodes and then assuming that the ones you care about will be both present exactly once and in the right order, I'd put the logic into c code. Loop over the nodes you're interested in and make one call to `getnodeset()` for each with a specific XPath. Then you can investigate the return value to determine whether the value is there or not and insert either that value, or some placeholder into your array at the desired location.

The way I'd do it would be to put the individual XPath expressions into an array and loop over it; then simply use the index in the XPath array as the index in the output array; that way the output values are always in a predictable location, but without the c code needing to know anything about the actual XPath, or what values are going where.